# filtering JSON data array by id

Tags: javascript, json

I am having issues filtering this results  by id

```
 "sectors": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "slug": "pilgrimage",
  "name": "Pilgrimage",
  "city_id": "1"
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "slug": "travel-preparation",
  "name": "Travel Preparation",
  "city_id": "2"
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "slug": "the-people",
  "name": "The People",
  "city_id": "1"
}
]
```

How will i filter this response by Id

Comment: please add, what you have tried and have a looke here, too: [mcve]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: use `filter()` method ..... just google

Comment: can you show a sample..  am new to this, i have tried alot

Comment: @user6601176 :  share the code that you had tried

Answer (score 0):

I don't think i understand you completly, do you want get one element of this array by him id?

if I`m correctly here the solution:

```
 var request = function(id){

    for(var i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
        if(object[i].id == id){
            console.log(object[i])
        }
    }
}
```

them when you call the function like `request(2);` return you object...

Comment: okay so it worked but i am having an issue

Comment: can you be more expecific in what issue you got?

Comment: The result shows up three times and i cant you variable id

Comment: <script>
var fetched_json = localStorage.getItem("cachedata");
var id = localStorage.getItem("guidecategory");
  var obj=JSON.parse(fetched_json);
  $.each(obj.sectors , function( key, value ) {
    var sectors = (JSON.stringify(value.name));
 var name = (value.name);
 var damnid = (value.city_id);
result = obj.sectors.filter(function (el) {
 var id;
 id = localStorage.getItem('guidecategory');
 var id = parseInt(id);
 console.log(id);
  return el.city_id == id;
});
console.log(result);
  var lines = [
  '</div>'].join(' ');
 $("#cities").append(lines);
  });
 </script>